# Draw Line Connecting two Object/Vector3 Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, line

I am making game .

In that i will have points(Stations) already given and on hitting those points, line should be started to draw till it reached to next point.

as well as i want to avoid overlapping of lines.

and line should continue to expand if i touch end of the line.

I know 2 approaches to draw line 
    I can use linerenderer or else i can use GL class .

I want to know which will be suitable for my requirement. and if you guys is having another idea then also you can share.

I have seen vectrocity demo but its not free so i cant use.

Thank you guys for your help and support till now and help me to solve my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the LineRenderer for a reasonably limited number of lines. It's much easier to customize than GL.Lines, and it will let you work in Unity's coordinate system without dealing with transform matrices.

And a small note: Up until 4.x, only Pro had GL.Lines, and it didn't work on iOS, so most people were using other approaches. I've never seen anyone use GL.Lines outside of a demo specifically to compare the two approaches. GL.Lines performs better, but is limited in customization options. Another approach I've seen is using the Graphics class and procedural meshes.It's also faster than the LineRenderer, but takes a little work to implement. [This](http://www.everyday3d.com/blog/index.php/2010/03/15/3-ways-to-draw-3d-lines-in-unity3d/) article comapares all three approaches and has some code for using the Graphics class

Answer (score 0):

For scene you can use GL.Lines or Debug.DrawLine or Debug.DrawRay. But this lines you can't see in your game. So use Line Renderer.

For you it can useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bqcu94VuVOI